# Prevent duplicate values in database - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one table that store values about recurrence of some events, for example, the event with `id=1` occurs in Monday, Wednesday and Friday, and the event with `id=2` occurs in Monday and Wednesday. So my table is like this:

```
id  event_id  day
1      1      Monday
2      1      Wednesday
3      1      Friday
4      2      Monday
5      2      Wednesday
```

My problem is that sometimes (not always) my script insert duplicate values in my database, so my table have twice the recurrence of event 1 and 2, like show the following table:

```
id  event_id  day
1      1      Monday
2      1      Wednesday
3      1      Friday
4      2      Monday
5      2      Wednesday
1      1      Monday
2      1      Wednesday
3      1      Friday
4      2      Monday
5      2      Wednesday
```

If I add a constraint `UNIQUE` in column `event_id` the event 1 only have the value Monday but I want that has the rest of values like Wednesday and Friday. How to add a constraint to solve this?

Comment: Add a unique constraint on `event_id` and `day` combined instead of a unique constraint simply on `event_id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a unique index on `event_id` *and* `day`:

```
create unique index idx_recurrence_event_day on recurrence(event_id, day)
```

This will prevent the duplication that you do not want.

If you already have duplicates there are various ways you can get rid of them.  However, it would be easier if you had a unique id for each row, which one reason why an auto-incremented primary key is useful in all tables.

One way to get rid of them even without a unique id is to use:

```
alter ignore table recurrence add unique (event_id, day);
```

Personally, I don't like this method because adding an index shouldn't delete rows, but this is a valid MySQL extension.

Answer (score 0):

[Mr. Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) provided the [right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29335919/3208640) but `if you cant's modify your schema`, you can also check on `insert` with [row subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/row-subqueries.html):

```
insert into table_name
select 1, 2, 'Monday' from dual
where (1,2, 'Monday') not in
(select id,event_id, day from table_name);
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3135d/1)

Or use `where not exists`

```
insert into table_name
select 1, 2, 'Monday' from dual
where not exists
(select 1,2, 'Monday' from table_name);
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/69e4c/1)

Comment: This is very useful too, but one problem that I forgot to mention in my question is that my database duplicate values, when a day passes , I don't know if my script have something wrong, but when I run the script the values inserted are correct.

Comment: yes of course there is other ways also, however as I mentioned the right way is right schema and creating unique index to prevent duplicate data, I just thought you my be have not access to create index.